# SQLite 3.7 .import (of csv) skipping records that SQLite 3.6 .import gets OK

Tags: csv, import, sqlite

I have 24,888 records that go into a SQLite table with FTS indexing. I load the table using .import from a set of .csv files with comma separators.

The platform is Linux - CentOS 6.2 with SQLite 3.6.20 as the supported version in this distribution.

*This has all been working* using FTS 3 to build a search system - with Apache and PHP.

To get FTS 4 functionality - with statistics I need - I recently manually updated to SQLite 3.7.13 - the newest.

Unfortunately, now when I import from .csv - whether to an FTS 3 or FTS 4 table I am missing over half the rows / records - I only get 12,224 instead of 24,888.

There are NO ERRORS reported during the import.

The last column in the data is a large (in some records) amount of text - up to 200K - 300K in a few cases. There are still some characters such as the curly double quotes or m-dash or n-dash in the text.

Is it possible that something is looking like end-of-file to the .immport code?

The word count utility 'wc -l' sees all 24,888 lines.

One final point, the .csv files were created using Python 2.6.6 running on the Linux system and any original line breaks were escaped (to ||) so I believe them to have uniform carriage control / line breaks. Maybe I'm missing some line-feed or carriage-return characters that SQLite 3.6 is ignoring but 3.7 is seeing???

I really need the additional FTS 4 capabilities (mostly to report statistics about search results using matchinfo) but it is no good if I cannot load all the data!

Thanks,
Laurence Brevard
San Jose, CA

```
[keywords2@keywords2c6x64 grant-import-tools]$ /usr/local/bin/sqlite3.7 --version
3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22 f5b5a13f7394dc143aa136f1d4faba6839eaa6dc

[keywords2@keywords2c6x64 grant-import-tools]$ /usr/bin/sqlite3 --version
3.6.20

[keywords2@keywords2c6x64 grant-import-tools]$ uname -a
Linux keywords2c6x64 2.6.32-220.23.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 18 18:58:52 BST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[keywords2@keywords2c6x64 grant-import-tools]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
```

Comment: I also tried this with a non-FTS table. SQLite 3.6 gets 24,888 rows, SQLite 3.7 only gets 12,244. So it's **not an FTS issue**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed mine.

Apparently double quote is now treated differently on comma separated files. I escaped them in the original source to two single quotes. After that all my lines import without a problem.

It appears that once there is a double quote in a field, everything until the next double quote is treated as a single field. I guess.

This is definitely different behavior starting after 3.7.7 and by 3.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same experience - when importing a large CSV (~7 million rows) 3.7 misses about 1 million rows whereas 3.6 doesn't